# How can I run sort of "for" statement via FQL MuliQuery

Tags: php, facebook, fql.multiquery

Basically,

I've got a function that runs through a user's entire friend list, then pick's up each friend's last status post.  Now, for someone that has 1500+ friends or even 300+ the time to exec adds up quickly.  I.e. running 100 friends through takes approx. 65 seconds.

So I figured, this would run better as a batch through MultiQuery.  Here's the basic concept:

```
$mq = array(
    "query1"=>"SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() LIMIT 5",
    "query2"=>"SELECT actor_id, message, created_time, permalink FROM stream WHERE source_id IN (SELECT uid2 FROM #query1) AND actor_id IN (SELECT uid2 FROM #query1)"
);
```

So this actually works great, however `query2` output's all the user's news feed; If I set it to `"LIMIT 1"` then that set's up the entire `query2` to be limited to 1 output instead of 1 output per user.

Any ideas or recommendations is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you need just the current status, you can just fetch "status" field of the user table. i.e.
    SELECT uid, status FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())

however this is a bit different if you need strictly the latest status of all friends of the user. But it will be much faster.

hope this helps